# how to save the fields in the table at different times

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I have an 100 fields in my table and I want to save some fields at a time and remaining fields at other time base.On what basis we can save remaining fields in the same record itself?

consider some fields are as follows-

```
createdDate = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today,**optional)
lendingProduct = models.CharField(max_length=50,**optional)
individual = models.CharField(max_length=50,**optional)
lendingPeriod = models.CharField(max_length=50,**optional)
investmentAmountStarting = models.IntegerField(**optional)
availableBalance = models.IntegerField(**optional)
firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100,**optional)
lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100,**optional)
password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
gender = models.CharField(max_length=50,**optional)
dateOfBirth = models.DateField(**optional)
cityOfResidence = models.CharField(max_length=50,**optional)
mobileNumber = models.IntegerField(**optional)
email = models.EmailField(**optional)
```

For example I have 100 fields(column) in my table at at the moment I am saving only 60 fields in the table, now I have 40 fields remaining , what should be the criteria to store remaining fields?

Comment: Where's you code?  We need a [mcve].  Refer to [ask].

Comment: While entering data first time you should have some primary keys(unique column or provide some unique id) in your table which you need to define , then whenever you add remaining fields just refer to PK and add the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a primary key for your table, (Django creates this by default, even if you don't define one of your fields as the primary key (id), see [Automatic Primary Key Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)

First time you save your data you create a new entry in the table with a unique id (created by Django, or a primary key chosen by you).

Subsequent saves would go to the same id (or primary key created by you)

Like so (assuming your model was named Foo),

```
foo_object = Foo.objects.get(id=object_id)
foo_object.individual = "bar"
foo_object.save()
```

Where object_id is the row to which you want to save the data to